# Use contents of .txt file in marquee

Tags: php, html, marquee

I'm trying to get  to use the contents of a local .txt file. In other words, make the contents of the text file (one line) to scroll across the page. I'm pretty sure what I've done should work but it doesn't, where have I gone wrong? Here's my code:

```
<head>
<?php
$myFile = "msg.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'r');
$message = fgets($fh);
fclose($fh);
?>
</head>
<body>
<div id="msg">
<font size=+3 face="arial black" color=white><marquee width="1280" style="position: absolute; top: 721px; left: 0px;"> <?=$message?> </marquee></font>
</div>
</body>
```

I have saved the file as .php but no text comes up. If I put a word into the marquee (instead of "?=$message?") it scrolls across the page just fine.

Please say someone can fix this, its doing my head in :S
Cheers, Tom.

Comment: Are you sure that short_open_tags is enabled? Try <?php echo $message; ?>.

Comment: The real answer is not to use the `marquee` tag

Answer (score 0):

Try

1) using `file_get_contents`

2) specifying full path to file in it.

```
<head>
<?php
    $message = file_get_contents("/full/path/to/msg.txt");
?>
</head>
<body>
<div id="msg">
<font size=+3 face="arial black" color=white><marquee width="1280" style="position: absolute; top: 721px; left: 0px;"> <?=$message?> </marquee></font>
</div>
</body>
```

(replace `/full/path/to/` with your real path to `msg.txt`)